# django static_url vs media_url

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

In settings.py I got media_url = '/media/' and static_url = '/static/'

In the urls.py I got:

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'show_indexes': True}),
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,'show_indexes': True}),
```

When I try to open localhost/media/ django correctly loads images placed in the media direcotry. But when I try to go to /static/  I get the:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    localhost/static/
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
```

But, when in the `setting.py` I change  static_url = '/sssstatic/', then the localhost/static/ works fine.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

Django *automatically* serves `STATIC_URL` when `DEBUG=True`. You don't specify it in urls.py. Or, if you do need to specify it for some reason you use:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```